# How to make an app to play ringer with behaviors similar to iphone native phone ring

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am working on a VOIP app on iOS. I have encountered some problems when implementing "Ignore incoming ringer" feature. It has the following requirements:
1. Should stop ringer if pressed screen lock or volume button
2. Should stop ringer if mute button is pushed to "mute" state
3. Should not play ringer if mute button is in "mute" state

Since iOS SDK provide no information of the phone's hardware buttons, I can only rely on setting AVAudioSession category. Before playing ringer, I set the category to ambient so screen lock and mute button can stop the audio. But this method cannot satisfy my requirements because app cannot play ringer when in background because ambient category cannot support background audio.
In order to solve this problem, I start playing the ringer in playbackandrecord category to make the audio stream come out and change the category to ambient immediately. Though it can meet my requirements, but this method caused many problems and bugs. For exameple, MPVolumeView cannot display the output devices correctly.

Can anyone provide a more elegant way way to simulate ringer? Or can this be done in iPhone?  Since it will be in app store, I cannot use private apis. Thanks in advance.